How to pass NumPy arrays into Rust function using PyO3?
I'm trying to pass a NumPy array into a PyO3 function in a Rust project. I'm not able to figure out how to get it to work.
I've tried this syntax:
#[pyfunction]
fn identity<'py>(py: Python<'py>, arr: PyReadonlyArrayDyn<f32>) -> PyResult<Bound<'py, numpy::PyArray<f32, numpy::ndarray::Dim<[usize; 1]>>>> {
    let len = match arr.len() { Ok(x) => x, Err(_) => 0 };
    let mut arr2: Vec<f32> = vec![0.0; len];
    for i in 0..len {
        arr2[i] = match arr.get_item(i) {
            Ok(x) => x.extract::<f32>().unwrap(),
            Err(_) => 0.0
        };
    }
    Ok(arr2.into_pyarray(py))
}

and this syntax:
#[pyfunction]
fn identity<'py>(py: Python<'py>, arr: Bound<'py, numpy::PyArray<f32, numpy::ndarray::Dim<[usize; 1]>>>) -> PyResult<Bound<'py, numpy::PyArray<f32, numpy::ndarray::Dim<[usize; 1]>>>> {
    let len = match arr.len() { Ok(x) => x, Err(_) => 0 };
    let mut arr2: Vec<f32> = vec![0.0; len];
    for i in 0..len {
        arr2[i] = match arr.get_item(i) {
            Ok(x) => x.extract::<f32>().unwrap(),
            Err(_) => 0.0
        };
    }
    Ok(arr2.into_pyarray(py))
}

But I get this error, regardless, when I try to use the function in Python:
>>> z = np.array([5.1, 5,3, 4.1, 6.4])
>>> temp.identity(z)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: argument 'arr': 'ndarray' object cannot be converted to 'PyArray<T, D>'

What am I missing? I've looked in the numpy crate documentation, but I couldn't find an example of passing a NumPy array to a function.
Update: It was suggested to use numpy::ndarray::ArrayD, but when I try this function signature:
fn identity<'py>(py: Python<'py>, arr: &Bound<'py, numpy::ndarray::ArrayD<f32>>) {

I get the Rust error
the trait bound `&pyo3::Bound<'_, numpy::ndarray::ArrayBase<numpy::ndarray::OwnedRepr<f32>, numpy::ndarray::Dim<[usize; 1]>>>: PyFunctionArgument<'_, '_>` is not satisfied
the trait `PyFunctionArgument<'a, 'py>` is implemented for `&'a pyo3::Bound<'py, T>`

So I still don't know what to do. Is it too much to ask the authors of a crate to document it? This is a simple use case and I have no idea where to find an example.

You left out the most important part of your code: how you create z.
numpy::PyArray is a python array, but as your error message shows, you are trying to pass an ndarray into it, which corresponds to the Rust type numpy::ndarray::ArrayD.

Cannot provide an answer, though, without seeing the code that creates z.

Also, if you want to get the maximum performance out of your code, make the result an ndarray as well. Raw Python arrays are much slower than ndarrays.

This is a solution that I found through experimentation:
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use pyo3::Bound;
use numpy::pyo3::Python;
use numpy::IntoPyArray;

/// Formats the sum of two numbers as string.
#[pyfunction]
fn sum_as_string(a: usize, b: usize) -> PyResult<String> {
    Ok((a + b).to_string())
}

/// A test function for verifying NumPy array functionality
#[pyfunction]
fn identity<'py>(py: Python<'py>, arr: Vec::<f32>) -> PyResult<Bound<'py, numpy::PyArray<f32, numpy::ndarray::Dim<[usize; 1]>>>> {
    let len = arr.len();
    let mut arr2: Vec<f32> = vec![0.0; len];
    for i in 0..len {
        arr2[i] = arr[i];
    }
    Ok(arr2.into_pyarray(py))
}

/// A Python module implemented in Rust.
#[pymodule]
fn temp(m: &Bound<'_, PyModule>) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(sum_as_string, m)?)?;
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(identity, m)?)?;
    Ok(())
}

Then after running maturin develop, the following Python code works:
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import temp
>>> z = np.array([5.1, 4.2, 5.2, 6.4, 4.2])
>>> temp.identity(z)
array([5.1, 4.2, 5.2, 6.4, 4.2], dtype=float32)

That being said, I don't know if this is the most efficient way to do it. It does make a certain amount of sense, though.
